dotnet produces two copies of an executable
The dotnet compiler produces two copies of the same executable and my google skills are not good enough to figure out why.
E.g. in a simple Console project:
dotnet publish --configuration Release produces bin/Release/net8.0/FizzBuzz and bin/Release/net8.0/publish/FizzBuzz, which are identical.
I want to build one optimized executable and one cross-platform executable. How do I do that?

EDIT: Thanks to @winscripter, I figured out the following:
dotnet publish -c . will produce:
bin/net8.0/
├── FizzBuzz (executable)
├── FizzBuzz.deps.json (not sure)
├── FizzBuzz.dll (cross-platform IL code)
├── FizzBuzz.pdb (debug symbols)
├── FizzBuzz.runtimeconfig.json (required for non stand-alone)
└── publish/ (a copy of the above files)

FizzBuzz.dll and FizzBuzz.runtimeconfig.json are needed for the FizzBuzz executable, which can be executed directly with ./bin/net8.0/publish/FizzBuzz.
FizzBuzz.dll can be run cross-platform with dotnet bin/net8.0/publish/FizzBuzz.dll. Only FizzBuzz.runtimeconfig.json is required for that to work.
The rest of the generated files are not needed for running the program.
I'm pretty sure that, without specifying the runtime option for dotnet, the default optimized build is for my platform, e.i. linux.

Because ldd reports linux specific dependencies:
ldd bin/net8.0/publish/FizzBuzz
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffd260e0000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fe955acd000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007fe955ac8000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007fe955800000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007fe95571e000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007fe955a9b000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fe955539000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fe955b05000)


I know that there are different build targets (OS specific, dotnet SDK specific etc) but I'm confused by the many options.
If you link to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-publish, please provide a description of the cons of the options, since I don't get them.
My FizzBuzz.csproj file:
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <AssemblyName>FizzBuzz</AssemblyName>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <!-- I added ErrorOnDuplicatePublishOutputFiles -->
    <ErrorOnDuplicatePublishOutputFiles>true</ErrorOnDuplicatePublishOutputFiles>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>

I added <ErrorOnDuplicatePublishOutputFiles> to see if that would change anything. It did not.
dotnet --version
8.0.301

uname -a
Linux kali 6.8.11-amd64 #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Kali 6.8.11-1kali2 (2024-05-30) x86_64 GNU/Linux


https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49939630/why-does-dotnet-publish-create-2-copies-of-the-same-files

Thanks @winscripter. That answers part of my question. dotnet build --configuration Release will build a cross-platform (but not OS optimized) dll file (not executable) that can be executed by the dotnet program. And it answers why there are duplicates. Now, how do I build one optimized executable? I imagine that means I can not build a cross-platform executable but need to use the dotnet program do execute the .dll file.

I'm not sure if it's possible to publish an executable that can run on multiple systems at once. In that case, you would need to use dotnet publish to publish multiple executables for multiple systems. So, dotnet publish --runtime win-x64 for Windows 64-Bit, dotnet publish --runtime linux-x64 for Linux 64-Bit, etc. On the other hand, dotnet build results in a dll that contains IL code which can run on multiple systems at once but required to be executed with the dotnet command.

This is going on a tangent but you provide useful information :) The only way I know how to execute the IL code in the .dll file, is with the dotnet program. What other options are there? I'm on linux, so that might hinder me in trying out Windows stuff.
Still I would like an answer to the remaining part of my question: How do I build a OS specific and optimized executable? Let's say for linux, if that helps. I now know I can do that with dotnet publish but don't think I really need all the stuff in publish - can I minimize the output somehow?

Actually! Sorry @winscripter I should have tried a little harder after your last comment. I think I got it. Thanks! I still get a lot of artifacts but I'm beginning to understand what they do. If you make the two points into an answer, I will accept it.

I actually began using the csc compiler from Mono now. It's a lot more bare-bone than dotnet but is perfect for my use-case. Which is getting up to speed with C# because I haven't written much since C# 2.0 (maaaany years ago).

With regards why there are two copies of an executable, see this answer:

dotnet publish builds the project before copying binaries to the output directory. The files you see in bin\Release\netcoreapp2.0\win-x64 directory are the result of dotnet build command. You could check it by running following command: dotnet build --configuration Release --runtime win-x64

With regards how to publish an executable to run on multiple systems at once: I don't think this is possible. When you use the dotnet publish command, it generates an executable that is OS specific (so one will run on one operating system only.) So, you would need to publish multiple executables in order to make the application cross platform, for example, dotnet publish --runtime win-x64 for Windows 64-Bit or dotnet publish --runtime linux-x64 for Linux 64-Bit. Or, use dotnet build to generate a dll file that contains IL code which can run on multiple systems at once, but it may require to be executed with the dotnet command.

I re-phrased my question to be more clear. I can now see that it was unclear, that I was asking, how to produce two distinct executables and not one, that was both optimized and cross-platform.

The go to doc here is .NET application publishing overview. First of all there are two main publishing modes: framework-dependent (the "default" one) and self-contained:

Both publishing modes produce a platform-specific executable by default. Framework-dependent applications can be created without an executable, and these applications are cross-platform.




Type
Command




framework-dependent executable for the current platform.
dotnet publish


framework-dependent executable for a specific platform.
dotnet publish -r <RID>


framework-dependent binary.
dotnet publish


self-contained executable.
dotnet publish -r <RID> --self-contained



You command - dotnet publish --configuration Release results on the framework-dependent executable for the current platform:

Publishing an app as framework-dependent produces a cross-platform binary as a dll file, and a platform-specific executable that targets your current platform. The dll is cross-platform while the executable isn't. For example, if you publish an app named word_reader and target Windows, a word_reader.exe executable is created along with word_reader.dll. When targeting Linux or macOS, a word_reader executable is created along with word_reader.dll.

So you will have the FizzBuzz executable (OS-specific) and FizzBuzz.dll which is actually a cross-platform one and can be run with dotnet command.
You should note that the .dll will actually contain CIL (common intermediate language) code which will be actually compiled to a platform-specific one when the app will be run (via the JIT compiler which is part of the runtime). There are cases when this is not desirable ("one time" console applications, possibly AWS lambdas and so on). In this case you can consider either ReadyToRun Compilation or Native AOT deployment (currently not every application type is supported).
Also worth mentioning - there is Single-file deployment option which can come handy in some cases.
