# win-x64 vs win7-x64 vs win81-x64, Windows RIDs via ASP.NET Core, hosted on Windows

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have an ASP.NET Core API app 2.1 , developed on windows 7, and hosted on production with Windows 2012 R2.

My question is that is win-x64 the best RID, and can be used on all Windows Platform? What are the procs and cons of using either of them (win-x64 vs win7-x64 vs win81-x64).

I cannot get a direct aswner from official link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/rid-catalog

Command below is used to publish the app

dotnet publish --configuration Release --self-contained -r win7-x64 --output C:\ASPCore

The app is hosted as Windows Service.

**Update**

[This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41766002/what-does-the-win-any-runtime-mean-in-net-core) doesn't explain on the newly introduced RID "win-x64". This is why the thread is created

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does the win/any runtime mean in .NET Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41766002/what-does-the-win-any-runtime-mean-in-net-core)

Comment: Thanks for the link, but it doesn't explain on the newly introduced RID "win-x64". This is why the thread is created.