# How resolve build issue NETSDK1056

Tags: c#, .net-core, .net-standard

We are currently facing an issue when building a project:

> NETSDK1056: Project is targeting runtime 'x64' but did not resolve any runtime-specific packages. This runtime may not be supported by the target framework.

There is two projects both are using netstandard2.0 :

- Project-A
- Project-A.Test

The error occurs on the .Test during the `dotnet build -r x64` command.
We need to specify x64 or x86 because we are using native library in Project-A.

I can't really find any information regarding "how to resolve runtime-specific" and I will appreciate any help.

Thanks !

Comment: this would be a good point to start and understand the use of 'x64': https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41766002/what-does-the-win-any-runtime-mean-in-net-core

Comment: Well, thanks for the link. However even with this understanding, it's quite difficult to see a solution to the problem.