# RuntimeIdentifier: win-x64 vs win7-x64

Tags: csproj, runtime-identifier

Which one is the more generic or appropriate one for *Windows 10 / 11*?

I know the [official chart from here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/rid-catalog) but I don't know how to read it.
Does `win-x64` include old stuff like *XP* and *Vista* and `win7-x64` is for *Windows 7 and higher* or is `win7-x64` specifically for *Windows 7* for some special reason and everything else falls under the `win-x64` umbrella?

**Edit:**

Found the answer [here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41863501/2334520)